# Mysql NOW() and PHP time()?

Tags: php, mysql, time

I am salting users' passwords with a mysql column which has the type timestamp and default is CURRENT TIMESTAMP.

Both of my timezones for mysql and php are identical.

My problem is this,

```
 $q = $dbc -> prepare("INSERT INTO accounts (password) VALUES (?)");
 $q -> execute(array(hash('sha512', 'somestaticsalt' .  $_POST['password'] . time())));
```

Now as you can see I have to hash with PHP's time function and on the mysql side it is a default timestamp.

Somewhere there must be an overlap because where users' are entering correct information it is still failing to match the hashed password in the database.

I have tried inserting time() into the joined column but it returns at 1970. Also I do not want to save the timestamp as an INT as this isn't the correct thing to do, so what is your thoughts?

Comment: bad idea, salt should be random.

Comment: No, salt should be UNIQUE, not random, randomness means not unique.

Comment: both, yours are predictable, that's problem.

Comment: @pv1 Is there a particular reason you cannot pre-save the time stamp?

Comment: That is why I also have a static salt. My question was not concerning my security it is concerning the difference in mysql time and php time in one query.

Comment: @DaveHolitish How do you mean? I haven't heard of this before.

Comment: You could always use $t = time() in between the 1st and 2nd line. Since your directly executing what you want directly after you should only have a variance of around 3ms. Which should only be 1ms more than the variance of what you would have normally.

Comment: @pv1 Also, I'm not trying to be rude or anything but I also want to point out that time() is always an int: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your salt really should be random.

A small improvement on your code (you could do a lot better, like use bcrypt or at least some stretching on sha512):

```
$salt = md5(time() . 'some-other-static-salt'); //more random than time() along.
$q = $dbc -> prepare("INSERT INTO accounts (password, salt) VALUES (?, ?)");
$q -> execute(array(hash('sha512', 'somestaticsalt' .  $_POST['password'] . $salt), $salt));
```

Now you're no longer depending on CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returning the same thing as time(), and you've got a better salt.

EDIT: if you insist on doing it your way, look at what mysql returns for that timestamp column.  I bet it looks like "Y-m-d H:i:s" and not like a unix timestamp.  Of course, you should have been able to figure that out yourself.  Assuming that's true, wrap it in strtotime and you might have some success.

Comment: Ye I will use your answer, but it is a mystery I why the figures wasn't the same, I was using strtotime(val)... Thanks for your input and reply